# How to plot x1, x2, x3 and more in the same plot?

Tags: r, plot

How to plot x1, x2, x3 and more in the same plot ? I am working in a small project, where I want to show all plots in the same plot.

```r
a  <- seq(-4, 4, 0.05)
x1 <- pnorm(a)
x2 <- pnorm(a, 2, 2)
x3 <- pnorm(a, 5, 5)

plot(a, x1, type = "p", col = "black")
plot(a, x2, type = "p", col = "blue")
plot(a, x3, type = "p", col = "red")
```

I would really appreciate if you just give me a `hint`

Comment: `plot()` opens a new plot window. Use it the first time only. After that, use `points()` which adds points to an existing plot window.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```r
plot(a,x1, type = "p", col="black")
points(a,x2,col="blue")
points(a,x3,col="red")
```

If you have question, let me know

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your time.

Comment: What about if we change the type?

Comment: It is the same, just replace the points with another type. For example, if the type = "l", in this case lines(a, x2, col = "blue")